# Programmatically Place View With Defined Fixed Contextual Filter

Tags: 8, views

I'm currently using the [starter](https://github.com/brynj-digital/starter) module which adds the Twig function `place_view()`. This works well in most cases, however I'd like to be able to pass another parameter to populate the fixed value given in a contextual filter.

**This would be my contextual filter settings:**
[image: Contextual filter settings]

**Here's the `place_view()` Twig function:**

```
public function place_view($name, $display_id = 'default') {
  $drupal = \Drupal::service('renderer');
  $view = views_embed_view($name, $display_id);

  if(! is_null($view)) {
    return $drupal->render($view);
  }

  return null;
}
```

Preferably I'd like to be able to use `place_view()` with a parameter to adjust that fixed value. It'd be even better if I could somehow reference the contextual filter I wanted to adjust the fixed value of.

Hopefully that all made sense, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Use [views_embed_view](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21views%21views.module/function/views_embed_view/8.3.x):

```
function views_embed_view($name, $display_id = 'default') {
  $args = func_get_args();
  // Remove $name and $display_id from the arguments.
  unset($args[0], $args[1]);

  $view = Views::getView($name);
  if (!$view || !$view->access($display_id)) {
    return;
  }

  return [
    '#type' => 'view',
    '#name' => $name,
    '#display_id' => $display_id,
    '#arguments' => $args,
  ];
}
```

Btw. [Twig Tweak](https://www.drupal.org/project/twig_tweak) maps this function one to one:

```
  {# This accepts views arguments as well. #}
  <dt>View:</dt>
  <dd>{{ drupal_view('view_name', 'page_1') }}</dd>
```

**Example**

So if you want to filter the node 123 in the contextual filter you've shown in the question, you use this as third argument:

PHP

```
views_embed_view('view_name', 'block_1', '123');
```

TWIG (using the module Twig Tweak)

```
{{ drupal_view('view_name', 'block_1', '123') }}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is useful. I'm still having trouble actually accessing these extra arguments inside the view though. As shown in my screenshot, I'd like to alter the 'Default Value' contextual filter, or use a different filter that allows me to pass a value from my template.

Comment: I've added an example.

Comment: In my screenshot I have the default value set to 'Fixed'. Surely passing a random parameter of some numbers won't replace my given value in the view settings with the one provided in the `drupal_view()` function?

Comment: Yes, it will replace the default value.